# How can I set the multiple background color in a page?

Tags: html, css

Hi and I'm new to HTML and CSS.
How can I set two background color in a page as the layout shown below?

[image]

How can I set one side is black color and another side is white color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use div tags and flexbox to do so. Refer the following code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
     <style>
          .container{
               display: flex;
          }
          .box1{
               background-color: red;
               height: 100vh;
               width: 50vw;
          }
          .box2{
               background-color: blue;
               height: 100vh;
               width: 50vw;
          }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
          <div class="box1">

          </div>
          <div class="box2">

          </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide it by sectors using the TAG `div`, giving it the properties of how much space do you want it to use, and to that div, give it a class to put the background-color property